# pycrypto AES CTR error: TypeError: CTR counter function returned string not of length 16

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto

In the following code, I've got an iv of length 16, and yet the interpreter is still spitting back a `TypeError: CTR counter function returned string not of length 16`

Here is the code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util import Counter

key = b'Jimmy ffffffffff'
IV = b'1234567891234567'

iv_int = int.from_bytes(IV, byteorder='big')

new_counter = Counter.new(16, initial_value=iv_int)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=new_counter)
output = cipher.encrypt(data)
```

It doesn't matter what I change my `iv` to, it still throws the same error. What did I miss?

I've also looked at the documentation and can't find anything wrong: https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/

Comment: First parameter of [Counter#new](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#Crypto.Util.Counter.new) is in bits, thus replace 16 by 128.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it.

Comment: @Topaco: Make it answer, it's small but worth it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the original pycrypto or pycryptodome?

Comment: Sorry just seen you're using original

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of [`Counter#new`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Util.Counter-module.html#new) is the length of the counter in *bits*. Therefore the value must be changed from 16 to 128.